# Split a component into smaller components react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

React tells us to divide the code as much as possible into components.
I have all this code, I have a table and in it there is a button that opens a dialog to enter data and save them with the handleChange function but having all this together, is generating that the data entry is very slow.

With the handleChange function, the OnChange event of the hooked form input style that sets the state of the object is handled.

If I make a console.log the value shows me the full value that I enter but in the state I am missing the last character in this case on 9

```
alias 123 456 789
State {"code":530,"email":"","alias":"123 456 78"}
```

What I want to achieve is to separate the table and the dialog into two different components

How can I separate the table from the dialog?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import {TextField,Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import  axios  from 'axios';


export default function dialog(props){ 


    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };

const initialState={code:0, email:'', alias:''}

const[subscription, setSubscription]=useState(initialState);

const handleChange=(event)=>{
    setSubscription({...subscription,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
}

const handleSubmit=(event)=>{

    event.preventDefault();

    if(!subscription.code || !subscription.email || !subscription.alias) 
        return
            const postSubscription=async()=>{
                try {
                    axios.post('/api/Subscription/add',subscription);
                    props.history.push('/Subscription'); 
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                }
            }
            postSubscription();
} 


const[user, setUser]= useState({Users:[]});

 useEffect(()=>{
    const getUser=async()=>{
            const response =await axios.get('/api/users');
            setUser(response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
    }
    getUser();
},[]);

return(
<div>
            <MaterialTable
            title="Users"
            columns={[
                  { title: 'Code', field: 'code' , type: 'numeric'},
                  { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
                  { title: 'Lastname', field: 'lastname' },
                  { title: 'Age', field: 'age', type: 'numeric'},
            ]}
            data={user.Users}
            actions={[
                {
                  icon: 'account_box',
                  tooltip: 'Add subscription',
                  onClick:()=>{ handleClickOpen()}
                }
              ]}
          />
                  <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                  <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscription></DialogTitle>
                      <DialogContent>
                          <DialogContentText>
                              Subscription
                          </DialogContentText>
                              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-name"
                                      name="code"
                                      label="Code"
                                      value={subscription.code}
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-name"
                                      label="Email"
                                      value={subscription.email}
                                      name="email"
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-multiline-static"
                                      label="Alias"
                                      value={subscription.alias}
                                      name="alias"
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <Button
                                      variant="contained"
                                      color="primary"
                                      type="submit">
                                      Add
                                  </Button>
                              </form>
                      </DialogContent>
                  <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
              </div>
        );
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but having all this together, is generating that the data entry is very slow"?

Comment: Please Provide more info on `What you want the Components to DO`. The Table and . the Dialog. If we do not know what you want to perform with these components we cannot help you very much. Also `@Akshit Mehra` Question is very valid as well..

Comment: I would also suggest, that if you want to really understand React, and Time allows it, to create re-usable Components for the Dialog and the Table. This will give you amazing insights on how things work, and allow you to manipulate how the component behaves instead of using them as is from the self.

Comment: @AkshitMehra 
When I open the dialog, when entering the data in the textfield it does so very slowly

Comment: @DimitrisEfst 
You're right, I already edited my question and I think it's a little clearer what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, despite my comment I will try and explain how I would evaluate the situation.

> This is just my own thoughts, derived from my own experience. It doesn't mean, it is the only or the best way out there.

I would go from the inside out. I would create a re-usable components for:

1. Dialog
2. Table

So, far so good. Just like you thought. On top of that, I would move all the SubmitHandlers and relevant Code to that Component(Dialog). Things like:

```
// This functions and all its dependancies, have nothing to do with the Table.
- handleClose
- handleChange
- open
```

> I would also, pass an array to the `<TextField />` Component in order to minimise code inside your render, and use an ES6 `map` like so:

```
 <Fragment>
   {TextFields.map(
     (field: ITextField):ReactNode => (
       <Fragment key={field.name}>{this.renderTextField(field)}</Fragment>
     ))}
 </Fragment>
```

With the above your `render()`, will be much more readable and you can extend the form much more easily in the future. `You just add more elements to the Array`.

As a last step, I would just call the Dialog and Table Component, inside a Parent Component. Just in case I needed to manipulate Data, coming from various sources(Redux - LocalComponentState) for both of those Components. Example:

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
 // State
 // Props

 render() {
   <TableComponent propsForTableComponent={propsForTableComponent} />
   <DialogComponent propsForDialogComponent={propsForDialogComponent} />
 }
}
```

Again, not sure what you mean by slow. But if I can be of any more help please ask. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks you gave me an idea of ​​how I can separate the component